# In-app billing testing RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm testing an app on my phone with a developer account and with test items (`android.test.purchased`). When I call the `isBillingSupported()` method, my `ResponseCode` is `RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR`. I didn't publish the app on the market, but I read that it is unnecessary because I use `android.test.purchased`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA"/>        
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

I uploaded it on the market as a draft, and still no luck... I'm losing my nerve...

Comment: I wonder why you got a -1, I just +1 you. Since in-app billing is tough to get working. All kinds of errors pop up. I wonder if a hello world will help http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/integrate-in-app-billing-just-3-lines-of-code-in-your-app/

Comment: Yes, I know... :) Thanks for +1...i finaly get it working... Thanks again Siddharth

Comment: What did you do to get it working, take a few minutes and update the group. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't remember...that was over a year ago...sorry...but i do remember that the right answer from above helped me, but there was something else... :(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the questions in your comments to @Samir's answer:

> "my question is do i need to sign an app for release"

Yes, you do.

> "do i need to publish on market???"

No, you don't.

Comment: Don't forget you do need to *upload* to the market, and your the APK you're testing needs to have the same version code as the market APK, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10622748/580677

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package name is correct.

Although you will eventually need to have the app signed for release ([how to do this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode)), you should be able to call `isBillingSupported()`WITHOUT signing the app, and have it return `RESULT_OK`as long as you have the BILLING permission on AND your package name is the same exact one for your app.  I was using a different, hard coded package name, and `isBillingSupported()`was returning `RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR`.

So here is my working code that calls `isBillingSupported()`:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();

try
{
    IInAppBillingService service = activity.getBillingService();
    int response = service.isBillingSupported(3, packageName, "inapp");
    Log.i("mylogtag", "response: " + response);
}
catch (RemoteException re)
{
    re.printStackTrace();
}
```