# Android In-app billing : "RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR"

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am unable to understand why i get a "RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR" in my implementation of "in-app billing".

What i've done :

- copy code from the sample application to my app
- android manifest contains the ""
- a test account declared in the Google Play console on a Xoom device under Android 4.0.4 with Google Play app version 3.5.19
- I am able tu use successfully the four reserved product ids : "android.test.purchased", "android.test.canceled", "android.test.refunded", "android.test.item_unavailable"
- declare my own product id
- my app is published on Google Play

The begining of exchanges with Google Play is :

- call "checkBillingSupported" from the service
- get a "onBillingSupported(true)" answer
- call "restoreTransactions" from the service
- get a "onRestoreTransactionsResponse" with "responseCode" equas to 5 (RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR)
- the UI says "This version of application is not configured for billing"

Then I am able to use the 4 reserved product id ?

Is there something i missed ?

Comment: are you sure you create signed .apk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The app needs to be signed with your production key *and* the one uploaded to Google Play should be the same version as the one you are testing with.

Comment: The client version needing to match the version on Google Play is the rub. If you are auto-incrementing your app's versionCode on source control commit then don't accidentally commit because you will need to deploy your new version to Google Play and wait an hour or more for it to propagate.